# Remove items from two lists based on value at index in either

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, filtering

I need to compare two lists and conditionally remove items from both based on the value of either item.

Input:

```
a = np.array( [1 , 2 , 3 , -1 , 5] )
b = np.array( [1 , -1 , 3 , 4 , 5] )
```

Required output:

```
a_filter = [1 , 3 , 5]
b_filter = [1 , 3 , 5]
```

I can easily get an array of list indexes where a "-1" value occurs using:

```
np.where( ( a == -1 ) | (b == -1 ) )[0]
```

But what is the most efficient way to delete these indexes from both list a and b? The only way I can think of is to reverse sort the identified index's and iter through both list removing them, however this seems quite inefficient.

List order is important as need to make confusion matrix, but don't want to compare -1 results.

Comment: consider the builtin function zip. Possibly inside a list comprehension with a conditional. Possibly unzipping to get the two filtered lists. edit: since they are numpy, go with the numpy answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could use boolean indexing:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array( [1 , 2 , 3 , -1 , 5] )
b = np.array( [1 , -1 , 3 , 4 , 5] )

mask = ~((a == -1) | (b == -1))

a_filtered = a[mask]
b_filtered = b[mask]

print(a_filtered)
print(b_filtered)
```

**Output**

```
[1 3 5]
[1 3 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [numpy.delete](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html) for this:

```
>>> a_filter = np.delete(a, np.where( ( a == -1 ) | (b == -1 ) )[0])
>>> a_filter
array([1, 3, 5])
>>> b_filter = np.delete(b, np.where( ( a == -1 ) | (b == -1 ) )[0])
>>> b_filter
array([1, 3, 5])
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you tag `pandas`

```
df=pd.DataFrame([a,b]).T
s=df[~df.eq(-1).any(1)].values
a_=s[:,0]
b_=s[:,1]
a_
Out[477]: array([1, 3, 5], dtype=int64)
b_
Out[478]: array([1, 3, 5], dtype=int64)
```